# Can I create 2 dictionary from only one loop over queryset

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-queryset

This is my code right now :

```
booking_data = {p: 0 for p in vehicle_category.types.all()}
vehicle_type_mapping = {k.id: k for k in vehicle_category.types.all()}
```

I wonder if there is a way i can create those 2 dict only with one loop. Or is there another way more efficiently that i can do.

Edited for more context:

```
    for vehicle_category in VehicleCategory.objects.prefetch_related('types').order_by('name'):
        booking_data = {p: 0 for p in vehicle_category.types.all()}
        vehicle_type_mapping = {k.id: k for k in vehicle_category.types.all()} 
        completed_booking_data[vehicle_category] = booking_data
```

Comment: You can, but in the end the number of "operations" is going to be the same

Comment: @DaniMesejo example, please? just curious

Comment: Re-iterating the same queryset object doesn't hit the DB twice. So, `vtypes = vehicle_category.types.all()` and then `for p in vtypes` (or comprehensions with it) as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
booking_data = {}
vehicle_type_mapping = {}
for r in vehicle_category.types.all():
    vehicle_type_mapping[r.id] = r
    booking_data[r] = 0
```

an alternative:

```
booking_data = dict.fromkeys(vehicle_category.types.all(), 0)
vehicle_type_mapping = {k.id: k for k in booking_data}
```

Both solutions call `vehicle_category.types.all()` only once, instead of twice.

Comment: i just edit my question for more context but your alternative seem fit to my problem